# Checkboxes inside a gridview ItemTemplate with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET GridView with Checkboxes inside an ItemTemplate. I am simply needing to check (with jQuery) whether any of them are selected so as to accomplish something else. Using the code below nothing is happening. If I give the CheckBoxes an ID it will work but only the first checkbox.

Here is the GridView:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" SkinID="GridView"
            DataKeyNames="Check Config">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Schedule ID" DataField="Check Config"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Check Configuration" DataField="Check Configuration" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Shift" DataField="Shift" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Earliest Time" DataField="Earliest Time" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Alarm Time" DataField="Alarm Date" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Disposition" DataField="Disposition" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Disable">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" CssClass="alarmSelections" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And here is the jQuery (edited for more clarification):

```
 //if some or all rows are selected, create the html button "btnEnterComment"
            $('[id$="gvData"]').change(function () {
                //check to see if the button already exists
                if ($('#divButtonHolder').hasClass('classFlag')) {
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    if ($('.alarmSelections:checked').length) {
                        $('#divButtonHolder').html('<input type="button" id="btnEnterComment" value="Disable Marked Alarms" style="border: 2px solid green; background-color: #fff;height: 25px; cursor: hand;"></input>');
                        $('#divButtonHolder').addClass('classFlag');
                    }


                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
// evaluates to true if one or more
// 'alarmSelections' checkboxes have been checked
if($('.alarmSelections:checked').length) {
    ...
```

Comment: I added/edited the code (see above) after implementing your suggestion. It still doesn't work and I wonder if I have messed up somewhere else in the function? "gvData" is the GridView ID.

Answer (score 1):

give your checkbox an ID chkABC

access all checkboxes using below syntax

```
$("[ID*=chkABC]").each(function(){
//use this. any property to play with each checkbox
})
```

when datagrid is rendered all control ids are generated dynamically. [ID*=chkABC] syntax will select all controls ending with chkABC name.

knowing this syntax is key to use jquery with repeater/datagrid kind of controls. I have struggled a lot earlier to find this solution. hope you will not struggle anymore.

Comment: I have added the whole jQuery function for clarification. I see what you're saying and am thinking I am messing up somewhere before this now.

Answer (score 0):

alarmSelections will return an array of checkboxes.

You have to use the .each(function(){code}) and loop through to see if there's anything checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id$="gvData"]')
```

If I'm brain-parsing this correctly, it's looking for a rendered element with an attribute that looks like this:

```
<sometag id$="gvData">
```

I'm not familiar with the "id$" notation you're using in the selector - is the "$" a wildcard or other special character?

Also, I don't think your GridView will actually be rendered with an id of "gvData".  ASP.NET will probably render it as "ct100_gvData", or something similar, to ensure uniqueness on the page.

In general, when I need to reference an ASP-generated control in jquery, my code looks something like this:

```
$('#<%= gvData.ClientID %>')
```

That should resolve to the "ct100_gvData" value, or whatever munged-together ID ASP.NET assigns the control when it's rendered.